# Netsuites Saved Search

Tags: oracle, netsuite

How can I add static data to a column in a saved search?

For example, I have a column that when I export to excel I would like to have 846 as the transtypeid.

[image: TransTypeID]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a formula numeric column and enter 846 as the formula

Comment: I tried that. It does not work. Even when I put it in quotes '846'.

Comment: I got it to work...I did not have it grouped. Thanks